# Automatically flow text between two columns in HTML

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I'm writing a program to shorten a radio listings HTML file - my wife has restricted vision, so we get a large text version of the listings as an HTML file, but it includes many stations of no interest, so I wrote a little program that removes their listing - otherwise printing it out takes around 100 pages! One station has just the programme titles, so it would save paper to display that listing in two columns. So, given a block of text such as:

```
<p>06.00 Joins BBC News</p>
<p>06.06 Weekend</p>
<p>07.00 Joins BBC News</p>
<p>07.06 Weekend</p>
<p>08.00 Joins BBC News</p>
<p>08.06 Weekend</p>
<p>08.30 BBC News Summary</p>
<p>08.32 The Conversation</p>
<p>09.00 Joins BBC News</p>
<p>09.06 BBC OS Conversations</p>
<p>09.30 BBC News Summary</p>
<p>09.32 The Lazarus Heist</p>
<p>09.50 Over to You</p>
```

Is there a simple prefix/postfix I can add which make this display in two columns? I want the text to automatically balance, if possible.

Comment: Use table instead ?

Answer (score 3):

Use `column-count`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

div {
  column-count: 2;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>06.00 Joins BBC News</p>
  <p>06.06 Weekend</p>
  <p>07.00 Joins BBC News</p>
  <p>07.06 Weekend</p>
  <p>08.00 Joins BBC News</p>
  <p>08.06 Weekend</p>
  <p>08.30 BBC News Summary</p>
  <p>08.32 The Conversation</p>
  <p>09.00 Joins BBC News</p>
  <p>09.06 BBC OS Conversations</p>
  <p>09.30 BBC News Summary</p>
  <p>09.32 The Lazarus Heist</p>
  <p>09.50 Over to You</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Auto Column in HTML</title>
    <style>
        *{
            padding:0px;
            margin:0px;
        }
        .col {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-areas: "a a";
            grid-gap:5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="col">
        <p>06.00 Joins BBC News</p>
        <p>06.06 Weekend</p>
        <p>07.00 Joins BBC News</p>
        <p>07.06 Weekend</p>
        <p>08.00 Joins BBC News</p>
        <p>08.06 Weekend</p>
        <p>08.30 BBC News Summary</p>
        <p>08.32 The Conversation</p>
        <p>09.00 Joins BBC News</p>
        <p>09.06 BBC OS Conversations</p>
        <p>09.30 BBC News Summary</p>
        <p>09.32 The Lazarus Heist</p>
        <p>09.50 Over to You</p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks both. The column-count solution works best for me - the text flows down one column, then down the next.